# Como puedo hacer que una función se pueda repetir hasta un maximo numero de veces?

Tags: python, function

Este es el codigo:

```
def user():
  
  user = str(input("Are you an student or staff?"))
  
  if user == "student":
    student()
  

  if user == "staff":
     staff()
 
  else:
    user()
```

Me gustaria que la función `student` se pudiese hacer 150 veces como máximo, y la función `staff` 20. Dentro de la funcion `staff` y `student` te vuelve a mandar a la funcion `user`(). La cosa es ponerle un máximo a cada una.

Answer (score 1):

También podrías utilizar un decorador:

```
def set_max(n):
  counter = {'n_ejecuciones':0}
  def decorador(f):
      def g(*args,**kwargs):
          if counter['n_ejecuciones']<n:
              counter['n_ejecuciones']+=1
              return f(*args,**kwargs)
          else:
              raise Exception(f"Se ha llamado más de {n} veces") #O lo que quieras hacer
      return g
  return decorador
```

Para aplicarlo a la función que definas simplemente:

```
@set_max(n=150)
def user():
    user_str = str(input("Are you an student or staff?"))
    if user_str == "student":
        student()    
    if user_str == "staff":
        staff()
    else:
        user()


while True:
    user()
```

La ventaja de esta forma de hacerlo es que es independiente de la función, por lo que lo puedes aplicar a cualquier función o quitarlo sin necesidad de modificar el código en sí. Ten en cuenta que también hay que ponerle el decorador a la función `staff`:

```
@set_max(n=20)
def staff():
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Una función puede tener atributos, como un objeto. Estos atributos se accesan con `nombre_funcion.nombre_atributo`.

Definamos una función que lleve la cuenta de las veces que se ha invocado. La cuenta se lleva en una variable llamada `cta`:

```
def fun(x):
    fun.cta += 1
    return x*x
```

El cuidado es que `fun.cta` no existe hasta que se inicializada en alguna parte, antes de la primera ejecución. Esto lo podemos hacer al comenzar el programa:

```
fun.cta = 0
```

En Python no hay variables privadas, así que la variable `fun.cta` está disponible para todo el mundo. Puede ser consultada para no llamar a la función una vez pasado el límite:

```
if fun.cta < limite:
    y = fun(x)
```

**Demo**

Recapitulando todos estas ideas, aquí tenemos un programa que itera 100 veces, pero que sólo llama a la función 20 veces:

```
def fun(x):
    fun.cta += 1
    return x*x

fun.cta = 0
for i in range(100):
    if fun.cta < 20:
        print(f"{i}. fun({i}) = {fun(i)} fun.cta = {fun.cta}")
    else:
        print(f"{i}. ")
```

produce:

```
0. fun(0) = 0 fun.cta = 1
1. fun(1) = 1 fun.cta = 2
2. fun(2) = 4 fun.cta = 3
3. fun(3) = 9 fun.cta = 4
4. fun(4) = 16 fun.cta = 5
5. fun(5) = 25 fun.cta = 6
6. fun(6) = 36 fun.cta = 7
7. fun(7) = 49 fun.cta = 8
8. fun(8) = 64 fun.cta = 9
9. fun(9) = 81 fun.cta = 10
10. fun(10) = 100 fun.cta = 11
11. fun(11) = 121 fun.cta = 12
12. fun(12) = 144 fun.cta = 13
13. fun(13) = 169 fun.cta = 14
14. fun(14) = 196 fun.cta = 15
15. fun(15) = 225 fun.cta = 16
16. fun(16) = 256 fun.cta = 17
17. fun(17) = 289 fun.cta = 18
18. fun(18) = 324 fun.cta = 19
19. fun(19) = 361 fun.cta = 20
20. 
21. 
22. 
...
95. 
96. 
97. 
98. 
99.
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir pero no sabria aplicarlo a mi caso. He actualizado el codigo poniendolo entero y como antes he dicho me gustaria que la funcion student se pudiese usar como maximo 150 veces y la funcion staff 20. Muchisimas gracias por tu atencion.

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos! Que hace que no puedas aplicar la solucion de Candid Moe a tu caso? Que esperas que suceda cuando la funcion staff se ejecute más de 20 veces?